# URL regex excluding a specific domain not matching correctly

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match some expression with regex but it's not working. I want to match a string not starting with `http://www.domain.com`. Here is my regex :

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(?!domain\.com)
```

Is there a problem with my regex?

I want to match expression starting with http:// but different from http://site.com
For example:

```
/page.html => false
http://www.google.fr => true
http://site.com => false
http://site.com/page.html => false
```

Comment: `^` outside a character class means "start of line", not "not".

Comment: Can you post an example of what you expect to/not to match but doesn't/does? The regex looks reasonable. Also there's no need to escape `/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to match a URL that does not have the domain you mention: `https?://(?!(www\.domain\.com\/?)).*`

Example in action: http://regexr.com?34a7p

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when the regex engine encounters the successful match on the negative look-ahead it will treat the match as a failure (as expected) and backtrack to the previous group `(www\.)` quantified as optional and then see if the expression is successful without it. This is what you have over looked.

This could be fixed with the application of atomic grouping or possessive quantifiers to 'forget' the possibility of backtracking. Unfortunately python regex doesn't support this natively. Instead you'll have to use a much less efficient method: using a larger look-ahead.

```
^https?:\/\/(?!(www\.)?(domain\.com))
```

Comment: The OP still needs to match lines starting with `http://` or `https://`, just *not* with the domain name.

Comment: Good point, while it shouldn't have an effect on the overall results of the expression, it could potentially make it much less efficient. I have changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You want a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
^https?://(?!(?:www\.)?site\.com).+
```

Which gives:

```
>>> testdata = '''\
... /page.html => false
... http://www.google.fr => true
... http://site.com => false
... http://site.com/page.html => false
... '''.splitlines()
>>> not_site_com = re.compile(r'^https?://(?!(?:www\.)?site\.com).+')
>>> for line in testdata:
...     match = not_site_com.search(line)
...     if match: print match.group()
... 
http://www.google.fr => true
```

Note that the pattern excludes both `www.site.com` *and* `site.com`:

```
>>> not_site_com.search('https://www.site.com')
>>> not_site_com.search('https://site.com')
>>> not_site_com.search('https://site-different.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a548510>
```

Comment: @guillaume: right, then still you need a negative look-ahead assertion.